# Use returned data from Ajax call, dynamic content

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to dynamically create some content using Ajax, php/Codeigniter and Javascript by submitting a form from a view to a controller that fetches and populates an array. The idéa is to fetch data using input from the form and create the charts (based on the fetched data) in the first view to be displayed in a pop up div.

I call this from the main view to submit the form:

```
function test() {
    var url = "path/to/controller/"; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(), 
        success: function(data) {
            $('#test-container').show();
            $('#test-container').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

to a function in the controller script that fills an array, let's call it fetchedData;

```
function getSomeData() {
    /* ..Fetching data.. */
    return fetchedData;
}
```

now I want to use that populated array in the first view where the Ajax call was made from in a pop up div like:

```
<div>
    /* ...Use the content of the returned array (fetchedData) to make some charts with javascript and php..  */
</div>
```

Nothing is being displayed since I am unsure of what to do to get a hold of the data in the array. Is this possible or it the wrong approach? Should I perhaps load the content as a new view in the controller and try to present that in the pop up div..?

Comment: What format are you getting it in: XML, JSON? These formats are much easier to use on the client side. I am not sure if we can just process the "fetchedData(a returned array)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different data types can be returned to the ajax request. This code

```
$('#test-container').html(data);
```

implies that - at the very least - plain text is being returned, although most likely the text includes html markup too. You need to know what **type** `data` is going to be in order to utilized it.  Understand too that `data` is whatever you echo out of your php function. The most common data types returned are text/html and json.

if `fetchedData` is an array then you want to return json which typically shows up at the browser as a javascript object.

By constructing an associative array in PHP like

```
$foo = 'fooish';
$bar = 123;
$out = array('somedata' => $foo, 'otherdata' => $bar);
```

and then echoing the json encoded version of this back to the client

```
echo json_encode($out);
```

the `data` object of `success` will look like

```
{somedata: 'fooish', otherdata: 123}
```

You can use standard javascript notation to access the properties of the object like this `data.somedata` or `data.otherdata`.

On the other hand, if you create some html and echo that back from the server

```
echo "<div class='cool-stuff'>The value of $foo is $bar</div>";
```

then `data` will contain the string  "The value of fooish is 123" and using the call `$('#test-container').html(data);` will likely produce an output in the browser. (It should anyway if an html element with the id of 'test-container' exists.)

I hope this help you get a handle on possible ways to get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

The "`return fetchedData`;" of a php function returns the data in PHP.

It does not however return "data" to the ajax function that called the PHP script.

To get the data back, you need to convert `$fetchedData` to a string and echo that string which then gets to the browser where your javascript function is running. And of course, you need to parse the string to turn it into an object.

So your php must encode the data, like so:

```
$data_json = htmlentities(json_encode($data));
echo $data_json;
```

And then you can parse the resulting json data into an object;

```
var data = $.parseJSON(json_data);
```